# perl encoding wrong when in Foswiki

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, foswiki

I'm using Foswiki and met really weird problem. I'm using LDAP server to authenticate people, and found entries with Chinese is encoded to utf-8 even if it's already utf-8. Here is what i did

1. I run this test codes in commandline, and gets the right output

> $str = "程洋" #they're chinese words  print STDERR "string is $str";
>
> $str =~ s/(.)/sprintf("0x%x ",ord($1))/eg;
>
> print STDERR "string hex is $str";

```
->程洋
->0xe7 0xa8 0x8b 0xe6 0xb4 0x8
```

I can't using `code sample` on these codes, seems that the string expression confuse the markdown system.sorry for that.

2. I run the same codes in Foswiki plugin system which is held by apache2,  in this environment, `print STDERR` will automatically redirect into /var/log/apache2/error.log, this time i get such output

   `->\xc3\xa7\xc2\xa8\xc2\x8b\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb4\xc2\x8b
   ->0xe7 0xa8 0x8b 0xe6 0xb4 0x8b`

As you can see, the words are escaped into url-like string, if it's `0xe7\xa8\x8b\xe6\xb4\x8b` Then i think it's alright, but they're encoded to utf-8 again even if it's already utf-8, but the hex is still OK. It not only happened to `print`, things on web page will also shows like this and result in mess codes of any Chinese words, why?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to support question 1817 http://foswiki.org/Support/Question1817.

I have no experience with the utf-8 support in Foswiki and don't know anyone who would have.

Suggest you post your question on Foswiki-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net. 
And state:

- Foswiki version
- perl version
- apache version
- operating system

It may get circulated to someone with the right skills.